# Navbar 100% page width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an HTML/CSS navbar that is 100% width of the screen.  Right now, it has small areas on the sides that aren't the navbar.

I'm not using absolute or relative positioning.

You can see my code here http://jsfiddle.net/una5kpx9/1/

```
    <div id="nav">
        <div id="nav-inner">
             <p>Text Goes Here &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav { float: left; clear: both; width: 100%;  padding: 0; background: #787F6C;}
#nav-inner { float: left; clear: both; width: auto; padding: 10px 20px; background: transparent; }
```

Any help appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Please add code snippet or fiddle.!

Comment: are you use the position:Absolute ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add:

```
body { margin:0 }
```

- Without: http://jsfiddle.net/9uzp5xgr/
- With: http://jsfiddle.net/r564nu9f/

Or if you want the navbar to follow when you scroll you can set the position to absolute:

```
nav {
position:absolite;
top:0;
right:0;
left:0;
height:50px
}
```